# How do I write a python function to count consecutive zeros in a binary representation of a number?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Given a number N, the function should convert the number to binary form, count the number of consecutive zero (the binary gap), and return the maximum binary gap. For example, 9 = 1001, the binary gap of length 2. The number 529 = 1000010001, has 2 binary gaps with length 4 and 3. If the number has 2 or more binary gaps, the function should return the maximum binary gap i.e. 4 in the case of N = 529.

I tried this function:

```
def solution(N):

  binaryN = bin(N)[2:] 
  n = len(binaryN)

  binaryGap = []

  for i in range(n):
    if binaryN[i] == 0 and binaryN[i + 1] == 0:
      m = len(binaryN)
    else:
      return 0
      binaryGap = binaryGap.append(m)
  return max(binaryGap)
```

The function returns 0 for all values of N which is incorrect. How do I debug/improve the code to produce the accurate result?

Comment: First thing is that your binaryGap = binaryGap.append(m) is unreachable code. i.e. The preceding return 0 means that it will never execute.

Comment: @bigkeefer do you mean I should write it outside the for loop?

Comment: No, it should be in the for loop, but you don't want to be returning a value (which terminates the whole function) in that else block of code as your loop has not done its full job yet. Also consider that your m = len(binaryN) is the full length of the original binary number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the below code. It would solve your problem.
The code is self-explanatory, yet let me know in-case of any doubts.

**The Code:**

```
import sys
num = int(sys.argv[1])

# Function to get the binary gap.


def binaryGapFinder(num):
    binnum = bin(num).replace("0b", "")  # binnum is binary form of the given number.
    i = 0
    x = 0
    x_list = []
    while i <= len(binnum)-1:
        if binnum[i] == "0":
            x += 1
            if i == len(binnum)-1:  # This loop will also consider if binary form is ending with 0. for example: 12 -> 1100
                x_list.append(x)
        else:
            x_list.append(x)
            x = 0
        i += 1
    return f"The Number: {num}\nIt's Binary Form: {binnum}\nMaximum Consecutive 0's: {max(x_list)}"


print(binaryGapFinder(num))
```

**The Output:**

```
python3 /the/path/to/your/script/binarygap.py 529

The Number: 529
It's Binary Form: 1000010001
Maximum Consecutive 0's: 4

python3 /the/path/to/your/script/binarygap.py 12

The Number: 12
It's Binary Form: 1100
Maximum Consecutive 0's: 2

python3 /the/path/to/your/script/binarygap.py 512

The Number: 512
It's Binary Form: 1000000000
Maximum Consecutive 0's: 9
```

Comment: Thank you @mrrobot.viewsource. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here worth mentioning to aid you. (Just a side note to start with is that, in Python, it's recommended/best practice to use all lower case for variable names, so I'll replace them in my examples below.)

The bin() built in function returns a string. So you should be checking for equality with "0" (or '0') instead of an integer. e.g.

```
if binaryN[i] == "0" and binaryN[i + 1] == "0":
```

With Python you don't need to bother with checking for lengths of strings (or any other iterables) to use in a for loop in scenarios like this. e.g. You can replace:

```
n = len(binaryN)
  for i in range(n):
```

with the more "Pythonic" way:

```
for bit in binary_number:
```

You can then use the variable `bit` (call it whatever you want of course, bearing in mind that good variable names make code more readable) instead of `binary_number[index]`. In this case, with each iteration of the for loop, bit will be replaced with the next character in the binary_number string.

From there on in your code:

```
m = len(binaryN)
```

will always be the same value, which is the total length of the string `binaryN`. e.g. 4 for '1001'.) This is not what you intended.

The first statement in your else block of code `return 0` will terminate your function immediately and return 0 and thus your binaryGap = binaryGap.append(m) code will never, ever execute as it's unreachable due to that preceding return stopping any further execution of code in that suite.

You've got the right idea(s) and heading towards the right track for a solution but I don't think your code, even when the issues above are corrected, will match all possible binary numbers you may encounter. So, another possible alternative (and yet roughly sticking with the solution I think that you had in mind yourself) would be something like this which I hope will help you:

```
def solution(n):
    binary_no = bin(n)[2:]
    binary_gaps = []
    gap_counter = 0
    for bit in binary_no:
        if bit == "0":
            gap_counter += 1
        else:
            # Encountered a 1 so add current count of 0's -- if any -- to list and reset gap_counter
            if gap_counter > 0:
                binary_gaps.append(gap_counter)
                gap_counter = 0
    else:
        # A for else suite (block of code) is run when all iterables have been exhausted.
        if gap_counter > 0:
            binary_gaps.append(gap_counter)

    if binary_gaps:  # If there is at least one element in the list
        if len(binary_gaps) > 1:
            return max(binary_gaps)
        else:
            return binary_gaps[0]
    else:
        # The list is empty, so no gaps were found at all. i.e. Binary number was all 1's.
        return 0


print(solution(529))
```

Comment: Thank you @bigkeefer. This was quite helpful.